# Tool to generate H264 Baseline profile with MPEG 2 transport stream container

Tags: windows, h.264

Is there any tool to generate H264 Video codec with baseline profile enabled on Windows.
Container should be MPEG 2 Transport stream(.TS).
I know one tool SUPER but it uses Main and Extended profile.

Answer (score 1):

[FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is a good way do do that. You can find [pre-built Windows binaries here](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/). See [here for a FFmpeg command line you can use to transcode an audio/video stream to h.264 into a MPEG 2 TS container](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/).